# Kubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 upgrade via iso

Tags: upgrade, 14.04, kubuntu

I can't upgrade through `do-release-upgrade` due to a slow internet connection, so I downloaded the iso file, and mounted it:

`sudo mount -o ro ~/kubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso /media/emcdrom`

It's mounted, ok, But there is no any autorun or *.sh's, so what I should do next?

p.s. i know, in old (10.*, 11.*) distributives it will be done by `kdesudo "sh /media/cdrom/cdromupgrade"` command, but, like i already said - there is no cdromupgrade.sh or any other *.sh. Only `wubi.exe` and grub boot core.

Comment: Can you run `kdesudo "sh /media/cdrom/cdromupgrade"`

Comment: There is no cdromupgrade.sh, there is no sh's at all.

Comment: Write the image to USB or CD and boot from it.